# Wrap a Flash Button Click as Click event of HTML Button/Div click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a flash button. I want to click that flash button from other HTML Button. That means flash click must trigger as the click of an HTML Button/Div or any other HTML object click event. So I can Call $(#).get(0).click(); and I can embed that flash click anywhere with HTML JS. Here is my sample code to understand the situation.

Note:

- I cant modify the flash.
- Must done at the client side only.
- I want to use flash only, no other HTML5 etc. solutions.

```html
<div id="test" onclick="alert("Hello");">
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="upload.swf" width="320" height="240" id="upload" style="visibility: visible;">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="wmode" value="direct">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <param name="flashvars" value="<parameters to flash>">
 </object>
</div>
```

In JS I am Trying

```js
("#test").get(0).click();
```

This is triggering the onClick event only. But I want that this will click the flash upload button for me as well.

Comment: I think for flash security purposes, you can not do that. So I think it's better to tell us why do you want to do that maybe we can find for you another solution.

Comment: actually I am calling an upload image button via iFrame section. The flash buttion is inthe main HTML file containing iFrame. So I want the same flash button to be clicked from iFrame. In order to communicate with iFrame (where iFrame content come from any host) I am using jStorage. When my defined variable change in jStorage from iFrame the upload flash button must be clicked from main html page. Where it looks like it is clicked from the iFrame.

Comment: I am using script cam library, thats why I cant modify the flash. And there is no such option in scriptcam.